# Integrability of the Poisson integral

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Maybe this is rather obvious, but I'm stuck. Let's consider the Laplace equation in the upper half plane with boundary condition $g$, $i.e.$
$$
\Delta u(x,y)=0, u(x,0)=g(x).
$$
Then the solution is given by the Poisson integral, 
$$
u(x,y)=P_y*g.
$$
Then I know some pointwise bounds if $g$ is good enough. The question is:

If $g\in L^p(\mathbb{R}),$ $1<p<\infty$, can I say $u\in L^p(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^+)$?

Answer (score 3):

Equation $\Delta u=0$ is called the Laplace equation, btw.

Edit. The answer to your question is no. 
Consider $f(z)=1/(z+i)$. On the real line it belongs to $L^p$ with any $p>1$.
In the upper half-plane it does not belong to any $L^p$ if $p\leq 2$.
If you want a real function, take a real or imaginary part of this.

Comment: Is your $f=P_y*g$ for some $g$? Maybe the result is not true for every $p$. Is the result true for $p=2$, i.e., given $g\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$, is $P_y*g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^+)$?